# Alternative to: Sorting List by two arguments with 'Key-Function'

Tags: python-3.x

Goal:

- Sorting List by 'Key-Function' with two Functions A, B
- Start sorting with Function A
- For each element, with the same A(element) value, sort those elements by B(element)

Problem:

- Function A is fast and efficient (duplicates can happen!)
- Function B is very slow but makes sure no duplicates occure
- `sorted(List, key=lambda element: (A(element), B(element)))` always sorts by both A and B, resulting in slow performance.

Plea:

- Please just nudge me in the right direction.

*Thankful for every anwswer*

Comment: You might want to sort values by A, compute B only for values with the same A, and then sort those sublists

Comment: @Riccardo Bucco, Thank you for your input. As to your Question: Both functions, A and B, return a rational number. Only B's result is more precice, has more decimal places. Regarding your suggestion it does work. As far as i understood you meant: `A_List = map(A, List)`;
`sorted_list = sorted(List, key=lambda element: A(element) if A_List.count(A(element)) == 1 else B(element))`. Or do you think it could be shorter / faster / better ? If that is the case just nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: Your solution might have complexity issues. Indeed, counting is an expensive operation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where the old `cmp` keyword is more useful. In Python 2, you would have written something like

```
sorted(List, cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(A(x), A(y)) or cmp(B(x), B(y)))
```

and `B(x)` and `B(y)` would only be called if `cmp(A(x), A(y))` returned 0, indicating that `A(x) == A(y)`.

Python 3 got rid of the `cmp` keyword argument to `sorted`, as well as the built-in function `cmp`, so you need to first reimplement `cmp`, then use `functools.cmp_to_key` to define an equivalent `key` function.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key


def cmp(x,y):
    if x < y:
        return -1
    elif x > y:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


sorted(List, key=cmp_to_key(lambda x,y: cmp(A(x), A(y)) or cmp(B(x), B(y))))
```

You can clean this up a little by folding `A` or `B` into the definition of `cmp` since we're writing `cmp` from scratch anyway.

```
def cmp_with(f, x, y):
    fx = f(x)
    fy = f(y)
    if fx < fy:
        return -1
    elif fx > fy:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

sorted(List, key=cmp_to_key(lambda x, y: cmp_with(A, x, y) or cmp_with(B, x, y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from collections import Counter

A_values = [A(e) for e in elements]
c = Counter(A_values)
B_values = [B(e) if c[a] > 1 else None
            for e, a in zip(elements, A_values)]
sorted_elements = [e for a, b, e in sorted(zip(A_values, B_values, elements))]
```

The solution relies on the fact that `None` values won't be used in the final `sorted` method when `c[a] > 1` (and so do `elements`).

The complexity is still O(nlog(n))